# Make the best use of?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

I'm applying to a college that accepts diverse students with different and unique backgrounds. Since I have lived in different countries and have a different experience, I wanted to say that:

> I believe that I could **make the best use of** my experience I had when I was living in a foreign country.

Does this make sense? And if there are any other ways to say this more formally, I appreciate your response.

Comment: It sounds nonfluent to say "my experience (that) I had" - we normally just say "*the* experience that I had".  After all, you could hardly have someone else's experience, so it sounds redundant to say "my experience that I had".

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear in this context what you mean by "making the best use of" your experience.

If you want to to emphasize that you have lived in several foreign countries rather than just one, you might rephrase your sentence to say: "My experience of living in (several) foreign countries has equipped me...."

The question then is to do what: To excel in your studies? To bring credit to the college? To display a certain maturity of purpose? To share your acquired knowledge with other students? You need to make this clear.